# IOS GCD port to Android cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

How to port IOS GCD to Android cocos2d-x?

If I want to achieve similar functionality which like IOS GCD on Android cocos2d-x.

As follows(code):

```
dispatch_async(
        dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),

^(void)

{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ (void) {
    });
}

);
```

Does anyone try do this? Please help me.

What should I do??

Answer (score 0):

Check out pthread. There is the official wiki described it.
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/How_to_use_pthread